# Delete SQL rows where value match from another table but not being used

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using Php my admin I would really appreciate any advice or help I am trying to delete address that is not in use based on columns from another table

I have 2 tables like this:

**tbladdress**

```
id         Address 
1222       add1
1332       add2
```

**tblcx**

```
name       location    Status
ana        1222        completed
ema        1332        used
ada        1332        completed
```

I want to delete rows that from tbladdress where id is equals to tblcx location which tblcx Status is completed while if tblcx Status is used cannot do any deletion

**desired output**

```
tbladdress

id         Address 
1332       add2
```

id 1332 were not deleted because it is still being used by another customer

I am using this query

```
DELETE tbladdress
FROM tbladdress t1 INNER JOIN tblcx t2 ON t1.ID = t2.location and t2.Status='Completed';
```

it gives me sql error

Comment: What SQL error are you getting? I would guess the problem is firstly that the first reference to tbladdress is meaningless, secondly that you are trying to delete from a join. I may be wrong about this, but have a think about syntax along the lines of DELETE FROM tbladdress t1 where t1.id in (select t2.location from tblcx t2 where t2.status='Completed')

Comment: And???  What' the error???  How do you expect us to help you if we don't know what's wrong with your query?

Comment: Its working thank it sql syntax Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined table aliases, so use them:

```
DELETE t1
FROM tbladdress t1 INNER JOIN
     tblcx t2 
     ON t1.ID = t2.location and t2.Status = 'Completed';
```